# how to get content from another module - symfony

Tags: symfony-1.4

I need to get fields from another module. How can I do this in symfony? 
(e.g.: I'm need something from module="x" to be working in the `showSuccess.php` from module="y")

Answer (score 0):

The only options I know would be either to make a com-class, which stores relevant values of other modules or to hand over the special information from Module x to y.

http://symphony-cms.com/learn/concepts/view/url-parameters/

Comment: Thank you but I already found the answer: just used `include_component` and it's working. Thank you anyway.